# How to customize the theme in ngx-bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-5, ngx-bootstrap

I have just started using ngx-bootstrap. I am wondering how can I change the look and feel of it, I mean how to customize the theme as we can do in bootstrap with scss variables?

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks